# What would this Java construct equate to in JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, constructor, jruby, processing

I'm in the process of porting some Java [processing code](http://glgraphics.sourceforge.net/examples/Integration/Neon/Neon.pde) to [ruby-processing](https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing), and I'm stumped by this Java construct:

```
new GLTexture[]{tex2, tex4, tex8, tex16}
```

tex2, tex4 etc are all instances of [GLTexture](http://glgraphics.sourceforge.net/reference/codeanticode/glgraphics/GLTexture.html).

It obviously maps those arguments to the GLTexture constructor somehow, but I can't see any constructors that don't require a *processing.core.PApplet* instance. Google is not much help as it's quite difficult to search for punctuation []{...}.

What would the equivalent of this construct be in JRuby?

Comment: On further research it appears to construct an array of GLTexture instances. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6432193&postcount=3

Comment: Yes. In Java, `new Type[] { val1, val2, val3 }` is a way to construct an array with the values val1, val2, val3. There actually is a search engine that can find symbols: http://www.symbolhound.com/

Comment: thanks for the symbolhound link echristopherson - very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby, this would just be `[tex2, tex4, tex8, tex16]`

Comment: (Unless you specifically need an array of GLTexture.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! the code is choking with this but I hadn't heard of to_java() before either - hopefully using this to create an array of GLTextures might do the trick.